# Pentaho report how to pass db instance via URL?

Tags: reporting, pentaho

## I have few apps, each one conected to it's database (MSSQL)

=> (1) pentaho server and severals common reports i would like to share between apps (every thing identic except data and logo).

=> (n) apps & (n) databases.

example:

- app1.mysite.net & db1 instance at db1.mydbs.net,
- app2.mysite.net & db2 instance at db2.mydbs.net,
- appn.mysite.net & dbn instance at dbn.mydbs.net.

Is were a way for each app to pass it's db "instance/name" through URL in order to retrieve it's own data report?

The goal is to reduce report maintenance sharing them across multiples apps and servers and also reduce cost avoiding multiples pentaho instances.